# Since upgrade to 18.04 libreOffice calc no longer imports xml

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice

Since I upgraded Ubuntu to the latest, the Data->Xml import in libreOffice Calc is greyed out and non functioning.

apt-get libreoffice reports that the latest version is installed.

Comment: In File -> Open it shows that it still opens XML files.  Under Data I see XML Source and not XML Import

Comment: 'xml source' is what I meant, that's how you import data into a table, at least it is when it works.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I think I found something that might help you.  **Warning:  This might cause Libreoffice Calc to be unstable.**

Click on *Tools -> Options -> Advanced*

Then click on *Enable experimental features (this may be unstable)*

[image]

After clicking OK it will prompt you to restart calc.  Then *Data -> XML Source* should now be enabled.

Hope this helps!